# Returning cell as a variable from function in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

My girlfriend needs to do something reasonably complicated with an Excel formula and I haven't been able to find an answer for her.

She wants to find the MIN of a range of cells, then, having identified that cell, use the 5 values to its right and left to calculate the average of all those values.

Is this possible?

Comment: If there aren't any limitations, you could do that using VBA.

Comment: What shape is the range of cells from which you need the MIN? Is it a single column or a row.....or a matrix (multiple columns/rows)?

Answer (score 1):

I have a formula that'll do what you've outlined in your question.

Assuming we're looking for the Min of a column (F:F), the following works:

```
=AVERAGE(OFFSET($F1,MATCH(MIN($F:$F),$F:$F,FALSE)-1,1,1,5),OFFSET($F1,MATCH(MIN($F:$F),$F:$F,FALSE)-1,-1,1,-5))
```

The letter F can be replaced in the formula for whichever column you're looking to use.

How this works is it fins the `Min` of the column, then using that to `match` to find the row number, then `offset`s to select the 5 cells to the right ( and a second offset that repeats and does the same thing reversed to the left). Finally, both of these ranges are used as an input for an `average` formula.

Answer (score 1):

For any single column or single row (where MIN value needs to be found) you can use this formula

`=(SUM(OFFSET(INDEX(Range,MATCH(MIN(Range),Range,0)),0,-5,1,11))-MIN(Range))/10`

Where Range is that single column/row

This excludes the MIN value from the average and should work assuming there are always 5 cells either side (e.g. MIN can't be in column A to E)

Comment: Also a good answer, I didn't think of breaking the average out into two steps like this as a method to exclude the look-up column's value. (so I used the average of two offsets)

Comment: Thanks Gimp - Also this will work even if the range is a row, e.g. it works for F2:F100 or F2:Z2

Answer (score 0):

I am only answering this question because of your girlfriend.

Say you have the below

[image]

Column F is the column you want to evaluate for the lowest value.
In this case, F6 is the minimum.  You would create a macro using the following code:

```
Sub test()

Dim val1 As String
Dim val2 As Long

val1 = WorksheetFunction.min(Range("f1:f10"))

For x = 1 To 10
    If Range("f" & x).Value = val1 Then
        val2 = WorksheetFunction.Average(Range("a" & x & ":k" & x))
        Range("m1").Value = val2
    Else
    End If
Next x

End Sub
```

The macro will find the lowest value in column F and then return the average value of the 11 values in the row in cell M1.